# Add a startup and shutdown configuration to AWS SageMaker notebook instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have 2 separate lifecycle configurations, one which will handle installation of various packages during the startup and one which will frequently check if the instance has been idle for a long period of time. Is there a way to combine both of these configurations into one and pass that as a lifecycle configuration associated with notebooks that I create?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single script for both and add it as an LCC to your notebooks. For example, you can add your `pip install` or `conda install` statements to this LCC script - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/on-start.sh and set it up as an LCC for your notebook.

You can also test it out by simply running the combined script from the terminal to ensure it runs without any errors, before associating it with the notebook.